# Getting updated textarea content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I have a textarea element, the content of which is created dynamically by jQuery, edited by a user, and then sent elsewhere via AJAX. However, as far as I can tell, the changes made by the user are not actually effecting the contents of the textarea at the DOM level, because jQuery/AJAX still sees the initial version rather than the edited version.

Is there any way to grab the current, user-edited version of the textarea's content?

Edit: Alright, I've fixed my issue. I had been trying to use $('#myTextarea').text() or $('#myTextarea').html() to grab the value, since textareas don't have a value attribute, but apparently jQuery's .val() is still the correct approach.

Comment: How are you currently getting the text area's content?

Comment: Can you show some code? Are you working with a textarea or a text editor?

Comment: Are you using a library, like CodeMirror?

Answer (score 0):

This will continually return the content of a text area (using jQuery):

HTML

```
<textarea id="area"></textarea>
<div id="out"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var value;
$("#area").on("keyup", function(event) {
  value = $(this).context.value;
  $("#out").html(value);
});
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/RY9AJ/).

Comment: This appears to be returning nothing at all, not even the initial content. Are you sure that should work, considering that textareas don't have a value attribute?

Comment: Well, it worked for me and then not. I've updated the example and added a JSFiddle. Let me know if it doesn't work.